# How load data and then insert it after another div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this div

```
  <div id="log1">
  </div>
```

Now I need to load log2 after log2 using jquery load method that end up like this.

```
  <div id="log1">
  </div>
  <div id="log2">
  </div>
```

This is not working...

```
  $("#log1").after().load("log2.txt");
```

somehow results are not what I want...

```
  <div id="log1">
                 <div id="log2"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` needs to load into an existing DIV. If you want to put the new DIV after another DIV, you need to use `$.get()` and call `.after()` to insert the new HTML in the callback function:

```
$.get("log2.txt", function(response) {
    $("#log1").after(response);
});
```

Comment: thanks barmar. 1. this works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/tqy7z734/.  2. Why it happend with out source?(log2.txt or any other file)

Comment: @PrashantTapase It doesn't matter where you get the HTML from. In the question, it comes from AJAX, in your fiddle it comes from a literal string. `.after()` will append the HTML the same in both cases.

Comment: @Barmar: yes i am agree with you. my question is different. 1. In above case div added in between div  2. In my case it added after div closed. why it happen with `after` http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/tqy7z734/2/

Comment: That's what `.after` does, it puts the argument HTML after the DIV. Your fiddle is making AJAX calls to pages that don't exist, so those aren't doing anything.

Comment: If you have a question that isn't about my answer, you should post a new question, not post comments here.